# grep returns matches that have this string as a substring

Tags: grep

I have a text file with two lines:

```
blah.linker  80 70
blah.linker-3.3985214612_4.7669276440_opt   62 32
```

When I try:

```
grep -w "blah.linker" file.txt
```

It returns both lines but I only want the first, an exact match. I have tried -F and -w...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding a space to the end of `blah.linker` ?

```
grep "blah.linker " file.txt
```

For tabs use

```
grep -P "blah.linker\t" file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but then grep returns nothing! Perhaps because it is a tab? I also added $'\t' to the end.

Comment: @Cokes -P lets you use perl regular expressions in your grep string